# 80's 90's female protagonist descending in a space elevator or a tall tree on another planet

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I read a book in the late 80's or early 90's that involved a woman special operative. She was descending in a space elevator or a large tree down to the planet and she had bio tech embedded in her. She might have been pursuing a criminal but I'm not sure.

Comment: Almost sounds like part of Matter, by Iain M. Banks, but that book came out within the last 5 years or so.

Answer (score 8):

Possibly Robert Heinlein's [Friday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_(novel)).  The main character is an artificial person with enhanced strength and reflexes who works as a courier and has a 'possum pouch' hidden behind her belly button which she uses to carry small objects such as microfilm.

> But maybe I had better draw a diagram first. I have a 'possum pouch,
>   created by plastic surgery, behind my bellybutton. It isn't large but
>   you can crowd one whale of a lot of microfilm into a space of about
>   one cubic centimeter.

The book begins with her on a space elevator referred to as the Kenya Beanstalk.

> As I left the Kenya Beanstalk capsule he was right on my heels. He followed me through the door leading to Customs, Health, and Immigration. As the door contracted behind him I killed him.
>
> I have never liked riding the Beanstalk. My distaste was fullblown even before the disaster to the Quito Skyhook. A cable that goes up into the sky with nothing to hold it up smells too much of magic. But the only other way to reach Ell-Five takes too long and costs too much; my orders and expense account did not cover it.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly Larry Nivens Rainbow Mars.
I do not remember there being an implant however.

the tree was called hangtree, it was over mars.